# Change overlapped image visibility on radio button click

Tags: html, css, radio-button, z-index

I want to change visibility options for two overlayed images for radio buttons. `.productbutton` appears as default, with `.productbutton_lower` with `visibility: hidden`. As a radio button becomes checked, `.productbutton_lower` becomes visible while `.productbutton` then becomes hidden.

**HTML**

```
<strong>Bottle Size</strong><br/>
<label class="prodbutt">
    <input type="radio" class="size" value="10" name="size" required="required" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VTMVEab.png" class="productbutton" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/k9JVWfr.png" class="productbutton_lower" />
</label>
<label class="prodbutt">
    <input type="radio" class="size" value="30" name="size" required="required" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KKsV0WU.png" class="productbutton" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/40ZKKJd.png" class="productbutton_lower" />
</label>
<label class="prodbutt">
    <input type="radio" class="size" value="100" name="size" required="required" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sEeIGxt.png" class="productbutton" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JBKhYI2.png" class="productbutton_lower" />
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
label.prodbutt {
    position: relative;
}
img.productbutton {
    height: 25px;
}
img.productbutton_lower {
    height: 25px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
label.prodbutt > input[type="radio"] {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
label.prodbutt > input[type="radio"]:checked + img.productbutton {
    visibility: hidden;
}
label.prodbutt > input[type="radio"]:checked + img.productbutton_lower {
    visibility: inline;
}
```

What is wrong with my styling here, why won't `.productbutton_lower` become visible after the radio button is checked? Additionally, forcing static visibility on `.productbutton_lower` gives odd positioning.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsu264fc/1/) (as an aside, how do you use SO's inbuilt fiddle?)

Comment: about SO snnipets: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues, (1) use general sibling selector `~` not `+`. (2) `visibility:visible` not `inline`.

```
label.prodbutt > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ img.productbutton {
    visibility: hidden;
}
label.prodbutt > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ img.productbutton_lower {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rsu264fc/2/

```css
label.prodbutt {
    position: relative;
}
img.productbutton {
    height: 25px;
}
img.productbutton_lower {
    height: 25px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
label.prodbutt > input[type="radio"] {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
label.prodbutt > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ img.productbutton {
    visibility: hidden;
}
label.prodbutt > input[type="radio"]:checked ~ img.productbutton_lower {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<strong>Bottle Size</strong> 
<br/>
<label class="prodbutt">
    <input type="radio" class="size" value="10" name="size" required="required" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VTMVEab.png" class="productbutton" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/k9JVWfr.png" class="productbutton_lower" />
</label>
<label class="prodbutt">
    <input type="radio" class="size" value="30" name="size" required="required" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KKsV0WU.png" class="productbutton" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/40ZKKJd.png" class="productbutton_lower" />
</label>
<label class="prodbutt">
    <input type="radio" class="size" value="100" name="size" required="required" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sEeIGxt.png" class="productbutton" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JBKhYI2.png" class="productbutton_lower" />
</label>
```

**Explanations:**

General sibling selectors `~` combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.

Adjacent sibling selectors `+` will select **only** the specified element that **immediately** follows the former specified element.

Lastly, `visibility:inline` does not exist in CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I had thought `+` would target the next element of a given class immediately following the parent element. `+ img.productbutton_lower` would target the next `img.productbutton_lower`, I didn't think it would only target the next child. Cheers!

Comment: It is a bit confusing sometimes, they both called *sibling selectors*, and can work the same way in some cases, also can be different in other cases. But there won't any more confusion once you know how exactly they work.